# Save lines of file in a char (*ptr)[LENGTH] structure

Tags: c

I wanted to read a File and save the lines in a `char (*ptr)[LENGTH]`. The basic idea behind my program is to compare lines from two files and notice the user about the differences between each line. The length of a line is fixed and the amount of lines in a file isn't. That's why I thought the data structure would be a good choice.

Now I just read the file line by line and want to save every line (mind that the length is fixed) with a pointer pointing to the char array that includes the line. Somehow it doesn't work though. I create a new char array every line to get a new address to get a new address for a line (but the address stays the same).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 50

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("test1", "r");

    char singleLine[LENGTH] = "";
    char (*ptr)[LENGTH];

    ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * LENGTH * 10);
    memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(char) * LENGTH * 10);

    while (fgets(singleLine, sizeof(singleLine), fp1) != NULL)
    {
        char tmp[LENGTH] = "";

        strcpy(tmp, singleLine);

        ptr = &singleLine;

        printf("\n%p\n", (void*) &tmp[0]);
        printf("\n%p\n", *ptr);

        *ptr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work though and I am not really sure where my thought process 
is wrong. Also I have a feeling there should be a more cleaner way to get the functionality I desire.

Thanks for any suggestions and tips!

Comment: Show a complete runnable main function.

Comment: `*ptr++;` is equivalent to `ptr++;`.

Comment: `singleLine` is unknown.  "This doesn't work" is vague.

Comment: You should do `(*ptr)++;`

Comment: Sorry, just updated it.

Comment: `ptr = &singleLine;` is just saving the address of the same buffer each time in the loop - not its contents.

Comment: Questionable allocation with `ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * LENGTH * 10);`.  I'd expect `#define LINE_N 10 ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr  * LINE_N);`